# debug_backtrace() fails while in output buffering callback

Tags: php, debugging, output-buffering, ob-start, debug-backtrace

Recently, an application echoed certain stuff at a random point of execution. Finding the exact statement turned out to be a problem: Too many statements emitted stuff.

Thefore, I registered a callback via [ob_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) to let the callback echo a [debug_backtrace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) and exit the application.

Note, that I tried to disable output-buffering as the first statement of the callback.

**Unfortunately, [debug_backtrace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) never returned anything. The app crashed as it called [debug_backtrace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) in the callback.**

I even didn't manage to save the contents of debug_backtrace() to a file (as opposed to stdout).

Could someone explain why?